# When i stored image Mysql using spring i have this kind of error?

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, blob

I use blob datatype in entity , 
private blob image;  // getter and setter created ....

I type this coding in controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value="save" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String save( @Valid Inpatient inpatient, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
{

    System.out.println("Name:" + inpatient.getImagename());

    System.out.println("Filename :" + file.getName());

    Blob blob =(Blob) file.getInputStream();
      inpatient.setImagename(file.getOriginalFilename());
      inpatient.setImagefile(blob);


        inpatientService.save(inpatient);
```

but i faced this kind of error

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0

Mysql also i declare blob only .....

If i use

```
@Lob
Private Blob image; // get and set
```

i have faced this kind of error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Blobs are not cacheable

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: sorry i don't know about stacktrace . can u explain elabarate....please

Comment: @muralidhartan - A stack trace is the information below the UnsupportedOperationException line. Basically, it gives a brief listing of what code caused the problem, usually with a method call, a file, and (if you're lucky) a line number.